# How to use the terms "fixed", "arbitrary", "fixed but arbitrary", "given", "for all" ... in proofs

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, terminology, proof-explanation

When I initially moved from Applied Mathematics background to Pure Mathematics (Graduate school), things were very tough in terms of proofs but they have gotten much better now. At those times, I couldn't explain what the following meant in proofs;

1. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given;
2. Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$ be fixed;
3. Let $x\in\Bbb{R}$ be fixed but arbitrary;
4. Take $n=N+1,$ for some $N\in\Bbb{N}$;
5. In particular, for $\epsilon=1/2$;
6. Let $\epsilon'>0$, for $\epsilon=\epsilon'/3$
7. Such that;
8. Whenever,
9. For each;
10. For all, and many more.

Could you please, explain these in details, perhaps, with some examples? That is, when to use them and how to... If you have other examples, I'd be glad to learn from you. Thanks

Comment: Related: [When do I use “arbitrary” and/or “fixed” in a proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46726/when-do-i-use-arbitrary-and-or-fixed-in-a-proof).

Comment: These four statements could be replaced with: 1. Let $\epsilon > 0$. 2. Let $n \in \mathbb N$. 3. Let $x \in \mathbb R$. 4. Let $n = N + 1$.

Comment: These fixed terms are somewhat arbitrary ...

Comment: "In particular, for $x=3$: we're going to temporarily let $x=3$ to examine that case, but $x$ is still a variable and not defined to be always $3$.

Comment: "Fixed but arbitrary" we can choose any value we like, but once chisen, it's a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given;** Take for example,  Prove that $1/n\to 0,$ as $n\to\infty.$

**PROOF**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given (it means give me a specific positive nuimber, say $\epsilon$, then I'd prove to you that$ \;\forall\; \epsilon>0$, $1/n<\epsilon$ for large n). Hence, given any $\epsilon>0$, choose $N=\left[1/\epsilon+1\right]$, then,
\begin{align} \dfrac{1}{n}\leq \dfrac{1}{N}<\epsilon,\;\forall\; n\geq N.   \end{align}
This implies that for all $\epsilon>0$, 
\begin{align} \dfrac{1}{n}<\epsilon,\;\forall\; n\geq N.   \end{align}

**2. Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$ be fixed;**

Pick a particular $n\in\Bbb{N}$ for the whole proof which cannot be changed in the course of proving.

**EXAMPLE 2**

Prove that for bounded positive real sequences $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$
\begin{align}  \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| \end{align}

**PROOF**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and $\beta:=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| $, then there exists $N$ such that
\begin{align}   \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|<\beta+\epsilon,\;\;\forall\;n\geq N. \end{align}
**Let $n\geq N$ be fixed,**
\begin{align}   \left|\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_N} \right|=\left|\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} \right|\cdot \left|\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \right|\cdots\left|\dfrac{a_{N+1}}{a_{N}} \right|<\left(\beta+\epsilon\right)^{n-N}\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}   \sqrt[n]{\left|a_{n}\right|}<\sqrt[n]{\left|a_N \right|}\left(\beta+\epsilon\right)^{1-N/n}\end{align}
Taking $\limsup$,
\begin{align}  \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\beta+\epsilon\end{align}
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, 
\begin{align}  \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| \end{align}

**3. Such that, arbitrary**

**EXAMPLE 3**

Prove that $f:X\to\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ is lower semi-continuous if

\begin{align}  \forall\;\lambda\in \Bbb{R},\;\;f^{-1}\left((\lambda,\infty] \right)\;\;\text{is open in}\;X. \end{align}
**PROOF**

Let $\lambda\in \Bbb{R}$ and $x_0\in X$  be **arbitrary, such that** $\lambda<f(x_0)$. Then, \begin{align}    x_0\in f^{-1}\left((\lambda,\infty] \right). \end{align} Take \begin{align}  V=f^{-1}\left((\lambda,\infty] \right),  \;\;\text{where }\;\;V\in U\left(x_0 \right).\end{align} Let $x\in V$, then $f(x)\in (\lambda,\infty] ,$ which implies that $f(x)>\lambda.$ Hence, for all $\lambda\in \Bbb{R}$ and $x_0\in X$ **such that** $\lambda<f(x_0)$, $f(x)>\lambda,\;\forall\;x\in V.$ This implies that that $f:X\to\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ is lower semi-continuous.

**4. Fixed but arbitrary, fixed, such that and whenever.**

**EXAMPLE 4**

Prove that $|x|$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, $x\in \Bbb{R}$ be **fixed but arbitrary** and $x_0\in \Bbb{R}$ be **fixed, such that** $|x-x_0|<\delta,$ then
\begin{align}  \left| |x|-|x_0| \right| \leq \left| x-x_0 \right|<\delta.\end{align}
So, given any $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon,$ then 
\begin{align}  \left| |x|-|x_0| \right|<\epsilon,\;\;\textbf{whenever}\;\;\left| x-x_0 \right|<\delta\end{align}
I pick any $x\in\Bbb{R}$ for the proof but it will be fixed throughout the proof.

Comment: Do you know of cases where given (from point 1), fixed (from point 2), and fixed but arbitrary (from point 3) are NOT interchangeable?

Comment: @Todor Markov: They, can be but I was trying to find other words of expressing them