# How do we translate between Logic and Mathematical English?

Tags: logic, article-writing

Take the statement "Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $z=ai.$" $(1)$

In English, this means "Let's choose any real $a$ then define $z$ such that $z=ai$ for that particular $a$ we have just chosen". All good there. We might use terms like "arbitrary constant" or "parameter" to describe $a$ too.

How do we write $(1)$ in formal logic?

I know that $\forall a \exists z (z=ai)$ is one option, but is that correct/the only one?

I know that $\forall a \forall z (z=ai)$ is wrong, and that so is $\exists z \forall a (z=ai).$

I know that "let" means to consider a specific real $a$ such that we can assume only that it's a member of $\mathbb{R},$ and $z$ if well-defined for this $a$ is defined for all $a \in \mathbb{R}.$ But then this implies $\forall a (z=ai),$ and it seems that each $a$ requires a different $z$ to make the statement true, i.e., $z$ depends on $a,$ yet $\forall a (z=ai)$ doesn't allow that.

Comment: Usually you would use this construction in a proof or similar place, where it would write as $\forall_a ((z=ai) \implies p(a,z,..))$ where $p$ is the statement you finally have at the end. Without such general context it does not make much sense because "let" itself is not introducing a proposition.

Comment: With no further context, how would you interpret "Let $z=ai$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: As a definition of $z$ given $a$

Comment: But the only thing we know about $a$ is it is real, so $z=ai$ for all real $a$, right? But is that not a contradiction? We can write $\forall a$ ($ai$ is an imaginary number), but we cannot write $\forall a$ ($z=ai$ is an imaginary number) (My choice of $a$ is permitted to be arbitrary)

Comment: Of course if you want to be very formal then you should actually consider $z$ as a function which assigns to each real $a$ the number $ai$, and consequently call it $z(a)$, but then it would be impossible to read any mathematical text.

Comment: You claim "Given an arbitrary real $a$, $z = ai$", from this we cannot conclude $\forall a (z=ai)$ as that is false. In the case of induction once we have proven $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ for arbitrary $k$ we can justify the $\forall$ quantifier, why can we not do that here? Is it correct to write $\forall a$(Define $z=ai$)?

Comment: A natural language sentence does not necessarily correspond to a complete proposition. It may well be that multiple sentences condense to one proposition. These discrepancies will **always** be there, because if there isn't, why make the effort in learning formal logic, since natural languages are already so close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Let" statements modify the context for subsequent content by introducing symbols and assumptions that can be referenced later. They don't translate to closed formal sentences themselves; the introduced variables are free until some later step produces a closed statement using e.g. [universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization). In your example this could be something like $\forall a\forall z(z=ai\implies zi=-a).$

Statements of the form "Let $v=\dots$" can also be regarded as introducing notational abbreviations instead of adding any formal content.

Comment: I just want to write $z$ in terms of $a$, there is no further steps, i,e I wish to be able to write sentences like "In particular, for $a = 1$ we have $z = i$", here $z$ and $i$ are equal only in the sub-context for which $a$ is chosen to be $1$.

Comment: If I wrote "Given $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we define $z = ai$" then I cannot generalise and write $\forall a (z=ai)$ because "$z=ai$" is not some property that I am assessing whether an arbitrary real $a$ has or not, we know to prove $\forall a P(a)$ start with proving $P$ for arbitrary $a$, then generalising, but this isn't possible in my circumstance.

Comment: @Mathguy you're describing a *definition*. A definition can be expressed as a natural language sentence but not as a closed formal sentence (unless you use a function symbol $z(a)$ as Michal suggests).

Comment: How do we write the definition in natural language (English) then?

Comment: You mention closed, how do we write an open sentence for the definition?

Comment: The open sentence is just "$z=ai$".

Answer (score 0):

Since this is only a part of a mathematical text, I suggest to write
$$a \in \mathbb R \land z=ai.$$
Since your text is not a statement, you cannot write it as a closed formula. When you prove the statement $a \in \mathbb R \land z=ai \Rightarrow \phi(a,z)$ for some formula $\phi(a,z)$, you can put quantifiers before: $\forall z \forall a (a \in \mathbb R \land z=ai \Rightarrow \phi(a,z))$; equivalently: $\forall z \, \forall a \in \mathbb R (z=ai \Rightarrow \phi(a,z))$.

I recommend you *not* to use formulae at places English is better understandable. From my suggestion, it is not clear that $a \in \mathbb R$ is a definition, so your sentence $(1)$ is perfectly fine. Definitions are usually written with colon, i.e., $a:=b+c$ or
$$(a,b,c) \text{ is a pythagorean triple} :\Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2=c^2.$$

For your definitions, this would give $a :\in \mathbb R \land z:=ai$, but I never saw the symbol $:\in$, so it would be difficult to parse.

I think the reason why I did not see the symbol $:\in$ is that this definition is not unique. Picking an arbitrary element of a set usually leads to open formulae as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> Take the statement "Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $z=ai.$" $(1)$

Here, you are assigning a denotation ($z:=ai$) and a restriction ($a$ belongs to a strict subset of the discourse domain $\mathbb C$).

And [in such statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4638411/21813), it is tacit that $a$ is arbitrary.

So, $(1)$ means

- Let $a$ be an **arbitrary** real number and let $z$ **denote** $ai.$

> In English, this means "Let's choose any real $a$ then define $z$ such
> that $z=ai$ for that **particular** $a$ we have just chosen".

Sure, but a key point of $(1)$'s intended meaning is that we are free to ***vary*** the value of $a.$

> "arbitrary constant" to describe $a$

Yes: in the large, $a$ is variable ("arbitrary"), while within any iteration of what follows $(1),\,$ $a$ has a particular value ("constant").

> How do we write $(1)$ in formal logic?
>
> I know that $\forall a \exists z (z=ai)$ is one option, but is that
> correct/the only one?

$(1)$ is the beginning fragment of a proof, and isn't really an assertion so isn't really an FOL sentence. After Universal Generalisation has been invoked, you might then end up with, for example,

- $\forall a{\in\mathbb R}\;\forall z{\in\mathbb C}\;(z=ai\implies iz=-a)$

or

- $\forall a{\in\mathbb R}\;(ai^2=-a).$